# RestKit deals with username and password strangely

Tags: nsurlconnection, restkit

I am using RestKit pretty basically with `RKClient` and doing a `get` request. My system uses username/password/account to authenticate the user. It is just httpbasic for username/password and the account is just a subdomain.

The issue I have is that if I do the following:

1. Sign in with the correct information (then it downloads all the data for the app)
2. Reset the data (this deletes all my core data objects and I also set the username and password of the shared RKClient to blank)
3. Put in the wrong username / password, but the correct account, then it will download data as if it was all correct.

I put puts before and after setting the username and password and I can see it is being changed to incorrect data. And I've set caching to be `RKRequestCachePolicyNone` (both on the shared client and on the RKRequest instance).

The returned request says it wasn't pulled from cache. And when I try to duplicate the issue in terminal using curl I get the correct response (that I can't get the data with the wrong username password).

So why/how would RestKit get the proper response back? It is hitting the server and getting a 200 response back.

### Example Code:

```
- (void)startDownload {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    NSLog(@"username and password before (%@,%@)",[RKClient sharedClient].username,[RKClient sharedClient].password);
    [RKClient sharedClient].username = self.login;
    [RKClient sharedClient].password = self.password;

    NSLog(@"username and password after (%@,%@)",[RKClient sharedClient].username,[RKClient sharedClient].password);

    NSString *base = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@.%@api",self.accountName,[defaults stringForKey:@"myURL"]];

    [[RKClient sharedClient] setBaseURL:base];
    [[RKClient sharedClient] setAuthenticationType:RKRequestAuthenticationTypeHTTPBasic];

    [[RKClient sharedClient] setCachePolicy:RKRequestCachePolicyNone];

    RKRequest *request = [[RKClient sharedClient] get:@"/verify.json" delegate:self];

    [request setCachePolicy:RKRequestCachePolicyNone];
}
```

### Update

I also noticed that if I put in the wrong password when first logging in and it comes back as a failure. If I then correct the password, it will always fail there after.

Comment: How about restarting your application and input wrong password at very first attempt? If you are using simulator also try reseting the entire simulator and re deploy your app again

Comment: It works properly if the username and password are wrong on the first attempt. I'm trying to figure out why this edge case doesn't work properly.

Comment: Can you please post your RestKit/Network logs? I'm curious whether RestKit receives an auth challenge in both cases (your 1st and 3rd step).

Answer (score 1):

Apparently Restkit stores some kind of cookie for authentication.
In my case I could log out and log back in with the wrong password as long as the username stayed the same.

In my case I could solve the problem with:

```
NSHTTPCookieStorage *cookieStorage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
for (NSHTTPCookie *cookie in cookieStorage.cookies)
{
    [cookieStorage deleteCookie:cookie];
}
```

Which got rid of all stored cookies. I hope this will resolve your issue as well.

Comment: I had the same problem and this little trick worked. I'm curious if anyone discovers what RestKit caches to make this possible.